# Core Data and CloudKit sync is inconsistent

Tags: swift, core-data, cloudkit

I have an app that uses Core Data and CloudKit using the public database. The problem is that deletes never seem to sync and additions and changes don't show up until the app enters the background and then returns to the foreground, and even those results are inconsistent.

The example app is just the default app you get when specifying SwiftUI and Core Data. I modified the Schema in the CloudKit dashboard to add the two indexes recordName and modifiedAt.

The following is the Persistence.swift file, so to reproduce, create a new project, chose Core Data and Use CloudKit, Add Capability for CloudKit and Remote Notifications, then replace the Persistence.swift contents with the above.

```
import CoreData

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
        for _ in 0..<10 {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()
        }
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
        return result
    }()

    let container: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "TestCKSink")
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        
        guard let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first else
        {
            fatalError()
        }
        //description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
        description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
        description.cloudKitContainerOptions?.databaseScope = .public
        container.viewContext.transactionAuthor = "Me"
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy
        
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {

                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I have tried this with and without the history tracking option turned on.  As I said, this works some of the time. I also realize that I need to add code to force refresh the display, but even checking the CloudKit dashboard and querying the records, some do not don't show there at all or take a long time to arrive (18 minutes).

Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: There is a [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10650/) on this it looks like you are missing some code from the basic setup such as `setQueryGenerationForm` you should look at the whole video but the code seems to be around minute 2:57

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That didn't help and when Nick Gillette reviewed the code, he left that code out of what was required to make sync work. Not quite sure what it does.

Comment: I did not resolve this issue entirely, but I suspect that what I was witnessing is some for of corruption in the public database that prevented synching from working 100%. When I switched from the public option to private, things began working. I suspect this was because I was starting from scratch again and do not know if there was anything significant about using the public database. I will eventually try to clear the public database and switch back to it and will post the results at that time. That may be awhile before I do that.

Comment: I believe the WWDC video from 2020 mentioned that only the private database would get push notifications. The idea is that the public database was for templates and rarer shared objects. So you would have to explicitly poll to get updates. Switching to the private database made it work. I don't like how this limits the use cases for core data backed by a public CloudKit database. The push notifications are supported on changes when you go straight to a Cloudkit database. I've had those subscriptions work in the past. I would be happy if there were an option to get that functionality!

Comment: I wasn't using "at" FetchRequest, instead using a routine to read the database directly. Once I changed this to "at" FetchRequest, it kind of worked, but I also found that the simulator rarely worked correctly, but actual devices did, with a few exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced similar issues some time ago, try the following setting when initializing your managed object context:

```
managedObjectContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
```

Comment: I already had that there. I'm suspecting that maybe my issue comes from the size of what I'm synching. Some of the text fields can be pretty big.